# chrome desktop notification without click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I spent last hour figuring out why I can not call without click event:

```
window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
```

I know it is working on click event but is there anyway that chrome desktop notification can be called without click event?

I tried create some html element and the try to simulate click but that is not working either.

I try using this http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/wT26x/1/ and it is working.

Comment: for security purpose, which seems obvious, you cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This need some use interraction:

### DOC

> **requestPermission** Requests that the user agent ask the user for
>   permission to show notifications from scripts.  *This method should
>   only be called while handling a user gesture*; in other circumstances
>   it will have no effect. This method is asynchronous.  The function
>   provided in callback will be invoked when the user has responded to
>   the permission request.  If the current permission level is
>   PERMISSION_DENIED, the user agent may take no action in response to
>   requestPermission.